# RobotC forwards command using wrong motors

Tags: robotc

I'm trying to run this simple program just to make my robot move forwards for 1 second using the **forward** command, figuring it would use ports 1 and 10 (main drive motors) because they are labeled as left and right drive. But when the command is ran it instead uses ports 2 and 3 for the claw movement. This is my project trying that.

```
#pragma config(Sensor, in1,    LeftLineSensor, sensorLineFollower)
#pragma config(Sensor, in2,    CenterLineSensor, sensorLineFollower)
#pragma config(Sensor, in3,    RightLineSensor, sensorLineFollower)
#pragma config(Sensor, dgtl1,  UltrasoundOut,  sensorNone)
#pragma config(Sensor, dgtl2,  UltrasoundIn,   sensorNone)
#pragma config(Sensor, dgtl3,  UpperLimitSwitch, sensorTouch)
#pragma config(Sensor, dgtl4,  LowerLimitSwitch, sensorTouch)
#pragma config(Sensor, dgtl5,  BumperSwitch,   sensorTouch)
#pragma config(Sensor, dgtl6,  ElbowEncoder,   sensorQuadEncoder)
#pragma config(Sensor, dgtl8,  ShoulderEncoder, sensorQuadEncoder)
#pragma config(Motor,  port1,  LeftDrive,     tmotorVex393_HBridge, openLoop, reversed, driveLeft)
#pragma config(Motor,  port2,  Claw,          tmotorVex393_MC29, openLoop)
#pragma config(Motor,  port3,  Wrist,         tmotorVex393_MC29, openLoop)
#pragma config(Motor,  port4,  Elbow,         tmotorVex393_MC29, openLoop)
#pragma config(Motor,  port5,  Shoulder,      tmotorVex393_MC29, openLoop)
#pragma config(Motor,  port10, RightDrive,    tmotorVex393_HBridge, openLoop, reversed, driveRight)
//*!!Code automatically generated by 'ROBOTC' configuration wizard               !!*//

task main()
{

    forward(50);

    wait(1);

    stop();

}
```

This is RobotC's method

```
#ifndef _FORWARD_H_GUARD
#define _FORWARD_H_GUARD

void forward(signed byte speed = 95)
{
  motor[port2] = abs(speed);
  motor[port3] = abs(speed);
}

#endif
```

I'm unsure how to fix this issue but I have gone into the RobotC method listings and found all the basic motor commands using ports 2 and 3 instead of 1 and 10, I've tried to change it to the right ports but got reverted multiple times. I understand I can manually make it go forwards but it would be nice to have the method.